# Convert the 8 bit number of a char to an integer

Tags: c

I have a `char x` and  I want to convert the 8 bit binary number of  x to an integer.

I tried it with  `int y=(int)x` but it doesn't work.

Has someone an idea how to solve that?

Comment: *doesnt work* means exactly nothing. Say what was x, what was expected y and what you obtained.

Comment: Please edit your question with more details. What you're describing should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you require

```
int y = 'x';
```

Comment: when i try this  gcc  says character constant too long for its type